# How do I use slots with a Quasar Dialog Plugin custom component?

Tags: quasar-framework

I want to make a custom component for the Quasar Dialog. And inside that component I want to use slots, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is my `CustomDialogComponent.vue` where I have defined a `cancelBtn` slot and a `confirmBtn` slot:

```js
    <template>
      <!-- notice dialogRef here -->
      <q-dialog ref="dialogRef" @hide="onDialogHide">
        <q-card class="q-dialog-plugin">
          <q-card-section>
            <strong>{{ title }}</strong>
          </q-card-section>
          <q-card-section>
            <slot name="cancelBtn" @click="handleCancelClick"></slot>
            <slot name="confirmBtn" @click="handleConfirmClick"></slot>
          </q-card-section>
        </q-card>
      </q-dialog>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { PropType } from 'vue';
    import { useDialogPluginComponent } from 'quasar';
    
    defineProps({
      title: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        default: 'Alert',
      },
    });
    
    defineEmits([
      ...useDialogPluginComponent.emits,
    ]);
    
    const { dialogRef, onDialogHide, onDialogOK, onDialogCancel } =
      useDialogPluginComponent();
    
    const handleConfirmClick = () => {
      console.log('Confirm Button Clicked');
      onDialogOK();
    };
    
    const handleCancelClick = () => {
      console.log('Cancel Button Clicked');
      onDialogCancel();
    };
    </script>
```

And the [Quasar docs](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#introduction) show that I can invoke it via a `$q.dialog({ ... })` Object. With props etc all set inside that object. So that would look something like this:

```js
    <template>
      <div @click="showDialog">Show The Dialog</div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup lang="ts">
    import { useQuasar } from 'quasar';
    import CustomDialogComponent from 'src/components/CustomDialogComponent.vue'
    
    const $q = useQuasar();
    
    const showDialog = () => {
      $q.dialog({
        component: CustomDialogComponent,
    
        // props forwarded to your custom component
        componentProps: {
          title: 'Alert title goes here',
        },
      })
    };
    </script>
```

But there are no properties inside the Dialog Object for  me to pass in my slots. So where can I pass in the `cancelBtn` and `confirmBtn` slots I created in `CustomDialogComponent.vue`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked directly and apparently there is no way to use slots at this time. They might add this functionality later.

Comment: Do you have a link to where you asked this? I'd like to upvote the feature request, thanks!

Comment: @morloch I asked it as a "discussion" not a feature request "issue". You may want to do that yourself: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar/discussions/12269#discussioncomment-2086273